# Changing image src adds to resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I have two images - one acts as a default state, and the other is used as a hover state. I swap them out like so:

```cs
$('.close-project').hover (e) ->
  $(@).children().attr 'src', 'images/close-button-hover2.jpg'
, (e) ->
  $(@).children().attr 'src', 'images/close-button2.jpg'
```

It seems that each time I hover, there is a GET request to the server, and another copy of this image to the resources (according to Chrome's Dev Tools). Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance for checking out this post.

Comment: sprite them and use as background, modify position with css and just change class when hovering

Comment: There is most likely something wrong with how your server is delivering the images such that Chrome doesn't know to cache them.

Comment: I was having trouble with using the images as CSS backgrounds - even if I preloaded them in my javascript by creating a `new Image()` and changing the `src` to match the image location, the images were the last thing to load on the page... any ideas on why that might happen?

Comment: Check whether your server is sending headers that are preventing caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the **img** source address create two image elements, one for the default image and one for the hidden image, and simply switch which one is visible when the hover event triggers.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <img id="default" alt="" src="default.jpg"/>
    <img id="hidden" style="display:none" alt="" src="hidden.jpg"/>
</a>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').hover(function () {
        $('#default').hide();
        $('#hidden').show();
    }, function () {
        $('#default').show();
        $('#hidden').hide();
    });
});
```

[Here is a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82PCA/).

By the way, you can also do it using only **css**, [check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TPL2/).